# WooCommerce price + ACF number field wrong summary

Tags: php, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I’m trying to change WooCommerce price based on an ACF number field.
My problem is that the sum of ACF number field + Product Price isn’t right.

```
$price_html = $product->get_price();
$x = get_field('custom-price');
$finalPrice = ($x + $price_html);
echo $finalPrice;
```

The value of ACF number field is 1,265 and the price of product is 5.
The sum I get is 6 instead of 6,125.
I tried to change the value to ACF field to 1.265 but i got the same result.

The problem is clearly with ACF field because if i set `$x = 1.265;` works

Comment: Try this `$x = (float)get_field('custom-price');`

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work, i'm still getting the same result.

Comment: in number field i think comma does not works

Comment: please check this it may help you `https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/insert-commas-into-acf-number-field/#post-83203`

Comment: Thank you. I tried with dot but didn't work either and i also tried with text field but still not the right result.

Comment: is that custom field is defined for all your products?

Comment: Yes. The problem solved by setting the field as number field and insert the value with comma. Thank you for your help!